# What's the difference between a function constructor and prototype constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I would like to know what the difference between this

```
 MyClass = function() {};
 MyClass.prototype.Foo = function();
```

and this

```
 MyClass = {};
 MyClass.prototype.constructor = function() {};
 MyClass.prototype.Foo = function();
```

when it comes to declaring the constructor function for a prototype in JavaScript.

What is the advantage in using `prototype.constructor` over a regular function?

Comment: How is `MyClass` initialized in the second example? `MyClass = {}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use object.prototype.constructor in OOP javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074556/why-use-object-prototype-constructor-in-oop-javascript)

Comment: The disadvantage seems to be that it does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the following image, taken from the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743):

[image]

When you create a new function, JavaScript automatically creates a new object (the prototype) as well:

1. JavaScript sets the `prototype` property of the constructor function to the prototype object.
2. JavaScript sets the `constructor` property of the prototype object to the constructor function.

Hence when you do this:

```
function Foo() {}
```

JavaScript actually does:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = { constructor: Foo };
```

Why does JavaScript do this? Consider what happens when you create an instance of `Foo`:

```
var foo = new Foo;
```

When you create an instance of `Foo` using the `new` keyword, JavaScript actually creates an instance of `Foo.prototype` and not `Foo`. This means that `foo` inherits properties from `Foo.prototype` and not `Foo`. To make this point clear:

```js
function Foo() {}

Foo.bar = true;

Foo.prototype.baz = true;

var foo = new Foo;

console.log(foo.bar); // undefined

console.log(foo.baz); // true
```

Now the advantage of having a `constructor` property on the prototype is that when you create an instance of `Foo`, the instance inherits the `constructor` property from the prototype. Hence you can use it to find out the type of an object:

```js
function Foo() {}
function Bar() {}

function test(obj) {
    switch (obj.constructor) {
    case Foo: console.log("It's a Foo."); break;
    case Bar: console.log("It's a Bar."); break;
    default:  console.log("It's something else.");
    }
}

test(new Foo);
test(new Bar);
test(new Object);
```

Beside that there's nothing really special about the `constructor` property of the prototype. It's just an ordinary property. In the words of Tyler Durden: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4X2AvfSTi6Q

Since it is an ordinary property you can decide not to have a constructor property at all:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = {}; // no constructor property
```

You can decide to make it point to some other function:

```
function Foo() {}
function Bar() {}
Foo.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

You can decide to make it point to something other than a function:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.constructor = "I am not a function.";
```

However, the point is that it's just another prototype property. In fact, we could use this to our advantage to create cleaner code. For example, this is how we normally create "classes" in JavaScript.

```
function MyClass(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

MyClass.prototype.sum = function () {
    return this.a + this.b;
};

MyClass.prototype.diff = function () {
    return this.a - this.b;
};
```

It's not very clean. Notice however that all three functions `MyClass`, `sum` and `diff` are prototype functions: `constructor`, `sum` and `diff` respectively. A prototype is just an object, and object literals in JavaScript provide a good form of encapsulation. We can use this to our advantage to write cleaner code:

```
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}

var MyClass = defclass({
    constructor: function (a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    },
    sum: function () {
        return this.a + this.b;
    },
    diff: function () {
        return this.a - this.b;
    }
});
```

That's much cleaner. In addition it shows us that the `constructor` property is just an ordinary prototype property. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: thanks for the great indepth answer. This was the clarity I was looking for. I really liked the `switch(..)` example.

Answer (score 0):

MyClass.prototype.Foo = function();
this code add a static function for class MyClass, which means its instances can accsee the Foo function via dot operator.
when we do new MyClass , first , we create a blank object like {}, and then we invoke the constructor on the object(MyClass.prototype.constructor.apply(obj, args)), at last, we set the prototype of the MyClass to the prototype of the object and return the object.
So, when you write "MyClass.prototype.constructor = function() {}", the second step above will do nothing.