# Javascript prototype chain behaves unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Here is my code:

```
var Person = new Function() // same as function Person(){}
var john = new Person()
```

now I have prototype chain like that: `Object -> Function -> Person -> john`

Now I am doing something like that:

```
Function.prototype.bar = "boo"
```

So I expect to have `Person.bar` and `john.bar` to be `"boo"`

```
Person.bar  // boo
john.bar    // undefined
```

so what happened? I dived into and found out that `john.__proto__` is prototype of Person, but `john.__proto__.__proto__` is NOT prototype of `Function`, it's prototype of `Object`, so I lost one piece of chain(Finction). that's why `john.bar` was `undefined`. So why is this happening? shouldn't I be able to access `Function` prototype properties from `john`?

Comment: It might help to note that `Person.__proto__` is `Function.prototype`. However, `Person.prototype` is not `Function.prototype`. It's an entirely new object. When you create an instance of `Person`, that instance inherits from `Person.prototype`.

Comment: you followed me on the right path. So if new instance inherits from  Person.protototype and that one inherits from Object.prototype, then why does Person have .__proto__at all which is Function.prototype? That's the real question

Comment: It's because that's the way inheritance works in JavaScript. The base object (i.e. the object you inherit from) is related to the derived object (i.e. the object that inherits from base) by the `__proto__` property. Hence, `derived.__proto__ = base` means that `derived` inherits from `base`. If you change this property then the inheritance changes as well. Let me update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following image taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307948/783743).

[image]

As you can see, when you create a function in JavaScript a new prototype object is automatically created as well.

```js
function Person() {}
```

Hence, the above code is actually:

```js
function Person() {}
Person.prototype = { constructor: Person };
```

Now, you should also understand that the `__proto__` property of a function is different from its `prototype` property.

```js
function Person() {}

console.log(Person.__proto__ === Function.prototype); // true
console.log(Person.prototype !== Function.prototype); // true
```

When you create an instance of `Person` using the `new` keyword, that instance object inherits from `Person.prototype` and not from `Person` or `Person.__proto__`:

```js
function Person() {}

const john = new Person;

console.log(john.__proto__ !== Person);           // true
console.log(john.__proto__ !== Person.__proto__); // true
console.log(john.__proto__ === Person.prototype); // true
```

The same goes for functions created by calling `new Function`.

```js
const Person = new Function;

console.log(Person.__proto__ === Function.prototype); // true
console.log(Person.prototype !== Function.prototype); // true
```

That's the reason why `john` does not inherit from `Function.prototype`. The prototype chain for `john` is as follows.

```js
      __proto__                     __proto__                     __proto__
john -----------> Person.prototype -----------> Object.prototype -----------> null
```

Whereas the prototype chain of `Person` is as follows:

```js
        __proto__                       __proto__                     __proto__
Person -----------> Function.prototype -----------> Object.prototype -----------> null
```

Here's the proof:

```js
const Person = new Function;
const john   = new Person;

console.log(john.__proto__                     === Person.prototype); // true
console.log(john.__proto__.__proto__           === Object.prototype); // true
console.log(john.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null);             // true

console.log(Person.__proto__                     === Function.prototype); // true
console.log(Person.__proto__.__proto__           === Object.prototype);   // true
console.log(Person.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null);               // true
```

This is because `Person.prototype !== Person.__proto__`.

---

Now, you may ask why do we have both the `prototype` and the `__proto__` properties. The reason for this is because an object in JavaScript (let's call it `derived`) inherits from another object (let's call it `base`) if and only if `derived.__proto__ = base`. Consider the following code:

```js
const base = { foo: 10 };

const derived = {};

derived.__proto__ = base; // derived now inherits from base

console.log(derived.foo); // 10

const newBase = { bar: 20 };

derived.__proto__ = newBase; // derived no longer inherits from base, it inherits from newBase

console.log(derived.foo); // undefined
console.log(derived.bar); // 20
```

Now, when you create an instance of a function the instance actually inherits from the `prototype` of the function. It doesn't inherit from the function.

```js
function Person() {}

const john = new Person;
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```js
function Person() {}
Person.prototype = { constructor: Person };

const john = { __proto__: Person.prototype };
Person.call(john);
```

Hope that clears things.

Answer (score 4):

When you have

```
var Person = new Function()
```

you get an empty function which does nothing and returns nothing, eg

```
function Person() {
}
```

When you create an instance of Person with `new`, the newly created object will look at `Person.prototype`, and since `Person.prototype` inherits from `Object` (not `Function`), you won't see the `.bar` property.

```js
function Person() {
}
const john = new Person();
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(john) === Person.prototype,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Person.prototype) === Object.prototype
);
```

It's really weird to try to create an instance of a function, but if you wanted to, I suppose you could get what you're looking for by having `Person` return a `Function` instance:

```js
Function.prototype.bar = "boo"
function Person() {
  return new Function();
};

const john = new Person();
console.log(john.bar);
```

I'd highly recommend not trying to create Function instances like this, though.

If you want an (odd) inheritance chain of

```
Object -> Function -> Person -> john
```

then you can use `Object.create`:

```js
//const Person = Object.create(Function);
// or
const Person = new Function();

const john = Object.create(Person);
Function.prototype.foo = 'foo';
console.log(john.foo);
```

Comment: I don't agree.. if you look into Person.prototype, you will find out that the constructor of Person is Function, not Object.  Object is constructor of Function.

Comment: So that makes me to think that Person inherits from Function

Comment: Yes I know that behavior. I just don't understand than why is Function(not Object) constructor of Person

Comment: checked and Person.__proto__  returns prototype of Function

Comment: so `Person.__proto__ === Function.prototype` . and you tell me that Person doesn't inheritss from Function?

Comment: I understand everything you said. But why is Person.__proto__ necessary at all if this _proto_ is not used for traversing from person instance -> Person -> Object.

Comment: Instances aren't supposed to be callable. Most of the time, you only have *one* `new` call when creating a prototype chain like that - the `new` at the very end, when an instance of a subclass is constructed.